# The diameter of the Erdös component of the collaboration graph

Tags: graph-theory, mathscinet

[This](http://www.oakland.edu/enp/trivia/)  site claims that the diameter of the Erdös component of the collaboration graph in 2004 was 23. What is it now? Is it increasing or decreasing with time? Recall that the vertices of the collaboration graph are mathematicians and two vertices are connected if the mathematicians co-author a paper. MathSci allows one to find the collaborative distance between any two mathematicians. So in principle one can find the diameter just by using MathSci.  In general (and more seriously) is there a mathematical theory which describes the growth of "real life" networks like the collaborative graph?

**Update 1** A process that I had in mind is something like this. At every step one of the following things can happen.

1. A new vertex $a$ is born with some probability $p$. Usually that vertex is a "student" of some other vertex $x$. We can connect $a$ and $x$ by an edge.
2. A randomly chosen vertex $y$ gets connected with a randomly chosen vertex $z$. But the probability for choosing $z$ is not uniform. Those vertices that are closer to $y$ have more chances getting connected to $y$.
3. A randomly chosen vertex "dies" (with some probability $q$) meaning it does not participate in new edges any longer.

**Update 2.**  Many thanks to Balazs and Joseph for their answers. But the first question still remains: what is the diameter of the Erdös component now?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferential_attachment

Comment: @Steve: Thank you! I meant something like that, but it is not quite the same as the collaborative graph. I explain what kind of process I mean in the Update to the question, because there is not enough space in a comment. 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a very large literature on this, written by people doing "network science". One of the names you might want to look up is that of Mark Newman, see for example his papers [The structure of scientific collaboration networks](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/cond-mat/0007214) or [Who is the best connected scientist? A study of scientific coauthorship networks](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/cond-mat/0011144) as well as [Clustering and preferential attachment in growing networks](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0104209). Another important player in this field is Albert-Laszlo Barabasi, whose group had a model (for the web graph) which is somewhat similar to what you suggest, [Emergence of scaling in random networks](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/cond-mat/9910332). Some of this work is reviewed nicely in [Statistical Mechanics of Complex Networks](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/cond-mat/0106096). The model by Barabasi et al is studied in mathematical terms by Bollobas-Riordan-Spencer-Tusnady's [The degree sequence of a scale-free random graph process](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/rsa.1009/abstract).

To answer your specific question on the diameter, I would expect it to be quite small ("six degress of separation"); whether it decreases in time must depend on the relative rate of birth of new vertices versus new edges (collaborations). If you take a finite graph and add completely random links, then already a few links lead to a diameter which is logarithmic in the size of the network. I think this remains the case also if you weigh your edge creation mechanism by the distance of the vertices; I once played with a model where the only new edges were created between 2-step neighbours, which still lead to small diameter.

Answer (score 7):

The paper "Some analyses of Erdős collaboration graph" by
Vladimir Batagelj and Andrej Mrvar
([*Social Networks*
Volume 22, Issue 2, May 2000, Pages 173-186](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6VD1-40B84V7-5&_user=825413&_coverDate=05%252F31%252F2000&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1535877740&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000044660&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=825413&md5=726818dbcd30e0e11e5f6540d2e86bff&searchtype=a))
is filled with fascinating data and analysis as of 2000.
(Because this is [now more than] a decade old, it does not answer your question.)
Here is their figure of "cliques of the main core," with many recognizable names
(if you can read them at this resolution!).

[image]

I see many (63) later papers that cite this one, but none that directly update it for this
specific Erdös graph.

Comment: @Joseph: Thanks! I did not know about this article. Do they consider the diameter also? I wonder if it was smaller or larger than 23 in 2000. I did not find it in the paper yet. 

Comment: @Mark: There were 17 connected components (after removing the Erdös-root!). One of them was large: 6045 authors. The diameter of that component was 12. They do not seem to report the diameter of the connected graph, but it might be implied by data in their tables.

Comment: @Joseph: Thanks for sending me the paper by email. I thought that 12 in the paper was the diameter of the Erdös component. In principle, it could be that for appropriately chosen parameters in "my" model (described in the question) one can get similar results. Then we would be able to predict the future structure of the mathematics community.  

Comment: @Mark, p.176: "The diameter of the large component in graph $E'$ is 12 with three diametric pairs of vertices..."  Not that it matters.
Re predicting the future of the math community: I assume you are kidding!  Regardless, collaboration may be stronger in Erdös-fields than in other areas of mathematics.

Comment: Laszlo Lovasz (in the clique above) just received the Kyoto Prize!

Comment: @Joseph: The growth of the collaboration graph, like any other large social network, may be approximated by some formal rules. Some "coarse" parameters of the network should be possible to predict. For example, will the diameter grow in time? At what speed? Will large highly connected clusters of nodes with relatively few outside edges exist for long time or will each of them break down after some number of steps (years), etc. You can check that the Erdös component of the graph actually contains all Kyoto prize winners (and all Fields medal, Wolff prize, Abel prize, etc. winners).

Comment: One question which occurs to me in relation to this is of generation - there are some people today, not unrelated to the clique above, who are having a major influence on the shape of mathematics to come.

Who will be the equivalent of Erdös, whose graph will be featured in 20 years time? And what other influences are there than those traced by such a graph (key textbooks, for example).

And who would you pick out in the generation before Erdös? Or does the graph and concept work for a generation because the definition and documentation of influence belongs to a specific generation?

Comment: @Mark: Stimulating questions!  Perhaps prior to Erdös there was never such a level of collaboration, which, for example, required
air travel.

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1016/S0378-8733(00)00023-X](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0378-8733(00)00023-X).

Answer (score 4):

In the long run, the diameter will grow.  Let k be an upper bound to the number of years between a mathematician's first and last publication. Then  nk years after Erdos' last publication, all new nodes in the Erdos component will have Erdos number at least n, so the diameter will be at least n.

(I am assuming here that there *will* be new nodes, which is not true for very large values of n. Also, I am assuming that k is constant, but only to keep the estimate "nk" simple.)

Comment: Of course, for my question to be non-trivial, one should consider the max. distance between "live" vertices only. 